# Run Windows services without administrator privileges

Tags: windows-server-2008, administrator, windows-services

How can I start and stop Windows 2008 services without administrator privileges?

I want to give a non-admininstrator user rights to start and stop Windows services.

Answer (score 7):

There are two different scenarios that could be interpreted from your post:

- A person who **does not** have administrator access wants to start services

In this scenario, it is not possible to start a service if the non-administrator user does not have the proper privileges. If you don't have privilege, you can't circumvent the permissions without some kind of crack that breaks the security model of Windows.

- A person who **does** have administrator access wants to confer the ability to start services to a non-administrator

In this scenario, the administrator **can** confer the ability to start services to a non-administrator, so this is possible.

From [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178633/minimum-rights-required-to-run-a-windows-service-as-a-domain-account):

> Two ways:
>
> 1.Edit the properties of the service and set the Log On user. The appropriate right will be automatically assigned.
>
> 2.Set it manually: Go to Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment. Edit the item "Log on as a service" and add your domain user there.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use [Service Security Editor](https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceSecurityEditor/) for a GUI to configure all services. You can set the exact user permissions for each service.

Answer (score 0):

Similar as for files also services do have an Access Control List (ACL) that specifies who is allowed to start/stop a service. The problem is that Microsoft never implemented a GUI nor command-line tool for modifying these ACLs.

There is a third party freeware tool called SCAcl that allows to modify service ACLs and as you require allow certain non-administrative users or groups to start and/or stop a service.

SCAcl
http://www.losoft.de/ls_scacl.html